# Accidentally removed https cert provider "JsafeJCE" - how to restore?

Tags: ssl, coldfusion, certificate, coldfusion-9

Because of a code mistype I accidentally removed the "JsafeJCE" cert provider from my ColdFusion 9 server. Is there any way to restore it? If yes, how?
Server and ColdFusion service have been restarted without a result.

While I Googled the problem I've read that in ColdFusion 9 Enterprise I just have to restart the ColdFusion service. But this didn't help. The provider is gone when I try to access it using:

```
<cfset local.objSecurity = createObject("java", "java.security.Security") />
<cfdump var="#local.objSecurity.getProviders()#">
```

It is ColdFusion 9 Standard on a Windows Server 2008 R2. The JRE is 1.6.0_17.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "removed"? Did you delete the file.

Comment: Ne, means I removed it by removeProvider("JsafeJCE") and because of a mistype in the code it wasn't reinserted after the http request.

Comment: The source of the problem was that I wasn't able to make a cfhttp request using https. So I tried a possible solution found on the web and mistyped the code. It suggested to remove the bugged ssl provider, run the request and reinsert the provider back to the jvm. I now solved it, updating the server to JDK1.7. Now the cfhttp works fine with https. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Cool, glad you got it sorted out. You might want to put that as the answer so other people finding this question will see it.

Comment: Done, Miguel-F. Thank you for taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem was that I wasn't able to make a cfhttp request using https. So I tried a possible solution found on the web and mistyped the code. It suggested to remove the bugged ssl provider, run the request and reinsert the provider back to the jvm. Because it seems I've deleted the JsafeJCE provider from my native CF9 JRE I had to solve it in another way.

I now solved it, updating the server to JDK1.7.0_79. Now the cfhttp works fine with https.

Doing that you have to change the JRE path in the jvm.config (located in {CF9_installpath}/runtime/bin) to the new jre directory of the JDK1.7.0_79 directory.
The last step is to copy the msvcr100.dll from the new JDK's bin directory to your Cold Fusion's jre directory.

If anyone is interested in a step by step tutorial for updating the underlying JRE in Cold Fusion 9, please let me know.